Using a table name as a variable with IF EXISTS
I need to make up a dynamic list of fields to link on for a Merge statement, but the table names must come from a variable.
I want to do the following with the table name as a variable and have tried doing this with the EXEC command, but it doesn’t work the way I thought it would.
Eg. This works with real table names:
IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'StackDetails' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'JOBID') 
BEGIN SET @linkcriteria = 'target.JOBID = source.JOBID And ' END
IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'StackDetails' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'stackid') 
BEGIN SET @linkcriteria += 'target.stackid = source.stackid And' END
…

And I know I can’t just do something like ether of these:
IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @Tablename AND COLUMN_NAME = 'JOBID') 
IF EXISTS (EXEC('SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =''' + @Tablename + ''' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''JOBID'''))

Although this works as a one-off command:
EXEC ('SELECT TOP 1 jobid FROM ' + @Tablename) 
But I can’t see a way of combining an EXEC with the above command.
Neither can I seem to put it into a variable:
DECLARE @temp nvarchar(max); EXEC @temp = ('SELECT TOP 1 jobid FROM ' + @Tablename); SELECT @temp

I thought the variable command would work but you can't use EXEC like that ether.
I know I can use a syntax like:
IF @Tablename = 'StackDetails'
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'StackDetails' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'JOBID') 
    BEGIN 
        SET @linkcriteria = 'target.JOBID = source.JOBID And ' 
    END
END

But I have a combination of 17 fields that can act as the unique identifier and up to 200 possible tables so this approach isn't really valid!
Any help would be appreciated.
The output of the stored procedure is a series of merge commands, for multiple tables.
E.g.
MERGE into StackDetails AS target
USING T_StackDetails AS source
ON target.JOBID = source.JOBID And target.stackid = source.stackid And 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT                  
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE  
;
MERGE into Equipment AS target
USING T_Equipment AS source
ON target.JOBID = source.JOBID And target.stackid = source.stackid And 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT                  
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE  
;
Etc…


EXISTS(EXEC...) isn't valid syntax, it's not working because it's not permitted. EXISTS expects a subquery. I suspect what we have here is an XY Problem.

Note that you really need to make sure you're escaping the names correctly using QUOTENAME(@Tablename)
